# Empty "Personal Information" menu title should be removed from per-site meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta

In each per-site meta, under the **Settings** tab we can see the list of menus.

In per-site meta, **PERSONAL INFORMATION** is not clickable, i.e. doesn't have any sub menu items. Maybe the menu title is copied from main site, where it has **Edit Profile** option in it and the tab name is **Edit Profile & Settings**.

Since in the per-site meta we are not able to modify any information about the user profile, so the unused menu title can be removed from the **Settings** tab in the per-site metas.

Screenshot from Meta Stack Overflow:

> [image: Per-site meta Settings tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems the bug has been fixed recently. There is no **PERSONAL INFORMATION** label in the per-site meta now.

I hope the fix is part of the [User preferences page responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369403/312043) change.

Screenshot from Stack Overflow meta site:

[image]