# User preferences page responsiveness

Tags: discussion, design, responsive-design, preferences

**Update 2021-09-07**

This is now live cross-network.

---

Now that the navigation of the [user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation) and settings are ready for responsiveness, we can start making individual pages responsive.

We plan on shipping a responsive user preferences page on Tuesday, September 7, 2021.

#### Desktop

[image: Desktop screenshot.]

#### Tablet

[image]

#### Mobile

[image]

Comment: Is there an estimate on the time to final delivery? Some of us are constantly fixing up our scripts (since they keep getting broken) and it would be nice to know if we can just stop trying and wait it out.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or if the changes aren't deployed yet, but for me not a single one of the profile pages is responsive. I can resize my browser window as much as I want, there isn't a single breakpoint in sight. And in general it would be useful to have a clear notice when and where this kind of changes are deployed, you mention a date but e.g. not if this goes to MSE first or will be deployed immediately network-wide.

Comment: @MadScientist This will be deployed network-wide ✌️

Comment: @Unconsidered The user preferences page will deployed network-wide on Tuesday, September 7, 2021. As far as deprecating all the mobile views and enabling responsive layouts on each page? We plan on being done by the end of 2021.

Comment: @AaronShekey OK. So in about 4 months. Is there an environment where we can test our scripts prior to your deployment? So no one needs to franticly make them work again in order to properly use the site?

Comment: @AaronShekey I'm not sure when exactly this happened but the best thing you did is making the "Settings" tab go directly to Preferences instead of "Edit profile". Getting to preferences was [indeed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/769478) too difficult ;)

Comment: @41686d6564 I'm glad someone noticed! I _think_ this is the right move. This was back when I introduced the `Edit profile` link over on the profile.

Comment: @AaronShekey Thank you for letting us know about this before you implemented the changes. Also, if it's not too difficult to do, please update your post with a several point summary of the main visual changes you're about to release. We will then not need to compare your screen shots with what we currently have to determine those main differences.

Comment: I only see this on prefernces and delete profile. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Luuklag Yep! A page at a time is the plan here.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Make either the entire row or *just* the toggle button clickable

Currently, both the toggle button and the area the contains the text are clickable. I think what should be clickable is either the entire row (more suitable for mobile) or the toggle button *only* without a label (probably suitable for both desktop and mobile?) - I personally prefer the latter but I'm not a UX guy anyway.

Here's a screenshot that shows what elements are currently clickable:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

As part of the preferences page change, [reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) help page needs to be updated.

Under the "But what if I still want to see those ads?" section, the wording "**Edit Profile &** Settings" should be renamed to "Settings" to matching with the current UI.
Or directly link to the advertisement section with the URL:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current#advertisements-setting

Also, the toggle related UI should be updated on the help page instead of the old UI.

Current preference page screenshot:

> [image: current UI]

Screenshot from the current reduced ads help page:

> [image: reduced ads]

Comment: You've got a good eye! Do your colleagues ever look at you funny when you're describing how to reproduce an issue you found because they can't understand how you thought to try that? If so, I feel we may have some things in common :)

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you. I'm a technical person, but usually helping my DEV teammates with manual/unit testing during the sprints. It helped them to avoid 50% of bugs before deployed to the QA environment.

Comment: I mean… the help pages being outdated after a site update is a constant on Stack Exchange. Similarly: missing translation keys for localized sites.